# What is the difference between "enfrente" and "frente"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

I was writing today and while editing I stumbled with this problem. Both words can be used but then again I didn't know the difference between them.

When should I use one over the other and viceversa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These sentences come to mind:

> El carro esta **enfrente de** ti.
>
> El carro esta **frente a** ti.

As you can see both means the same thing but they use different preposition.

**RAE**:

> **enfrente**.
>
> (De en- y frente).
>
> 1. adv. l. A la parte opuesta, en punto que mira a otro, o que está delante de otro.
> 2. adv. m. En contra, en pugna.
>
> **frente**: en ~.
>
> 1. loc. adv. enfrente.

Answer (score 6):

**enfrente** ([RAE definition](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=enfrente), [WordReference definition](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=enfrente)) is an adverb of location typically meaning "opposite" or "front."

**frente** ([RAE definition](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=frente), [WordReference definition](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=frente)) can be a feminine noun referring to the forehead, a masculine noun referring to a "front" (in many different senses), or an adverb that is synonymous with *enfrente*.

**enfrente de** and **frente a** generally mean the same thing and can be used interchangeably.

The problem for language learners arises in the various ways both words (and others, like *delante*) can be used to express the English concept of "front". In his book *Breaking Out of Beginner's Spanish*, Joseph J. Keenan writes:

> *Al frente de* is usually the expression for the English "in front of." It means "at (in) the front part of (something)." In the earlier example, a fountain that is *al frente de la casa* is on the property at the front of the house. Next come a host of prepositional expressions that, in many circumstances, mean "in front of" but generally only in the sense of "facing." *Enfrente de* is one of those expressions, and it is better regarded as a trickster (see Chapter 3). Think of it as a synonym for "facing" or "across the way." A fountain that is *enfrente de la casa* is likely to be across the street from the house. *Frente a* means much the same and should be viewed as just as unreliable as *enfrente de* in most cases. Sometimes the act of "facing" is implicit. *Lo tienes frente a los ojos* = "You have it in front of your eyes"--that is, "staring you in the face." *De frente a*, finally, states very clearly that something is "face to face," literally "with its front facing (something)." *Estoy parada de frente al sol* = "I'm standing facing the sun."
>
> Perhaps the safest word of all for "in front of" is *delante*, usually followed by *de*. Generally, whenever you can use "ahead" or "ahead of," you should probably be using *delante* or *delante de*. but it also covers a wide range of "in front of" situations. The fountain can be *delante de la casa*, for instance. *Bob se sienta delante de mí en la clase* = "Bob sits ahead of me in class."

He goes on to describe how *adelante* generally translates "up front" and *el frente* usually translates "the front" or "the front part" of something.